# How to produce a particular type of letter S

Tags: beamer, math-mode, alphabet

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
$\boldsymbol{\mathbb{S}}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following letter S in the middle of a Beamer frame:

[image]

However, in another document was not written by me and that includes many more packages for various purposes, the output is this:

[image]

How can I produce this second version of the letter S? I suspect a missing package is the issue, but I'm confused as my code doesn't generate any errors. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try commenting out the line `\usepackage{bbold}`, which is providing this different blackboard bold symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only has to do with the particular blackboard bold font (that used with `\mathbb`) you're using. In your MWE, the package [`bbold`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bbold) defines the blackboard bold font and the S you're seeing comes from this font.

To change the font, simply change the package that loads it. I especially like to use [`mathalpha`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha), because it allows to choose easily between many different fonts. See the documentation of the package for examples.

I think the S you're looking for is that of the Fourier blackboard bold font, that can be loaded by loading `mathalpha` with the option `bb=fourier`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bb=fourier]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\(\mathbb{S}\)
\end{document}
```

There is no problem in using the same package in `beamer` as well: replacing the line

```
\usepackage{bbold}
```

with

```
\usepackage[bb=fourier]{mathalpha}
```

in your MWE outputs the same symbol.

Answer (score 3):

I would replace

```
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
```

with

```
\usepackage[bb=esstix, scr=rsfs, cal=euler]{mathalfa}
```

The `mathalfa` package (the spelling "mathalpha" is ok too...) provides a very nice interface for choosing from lots and lots of blackboard-bold, fraktur, calligraphic, and script math fonts. As you've probably guessed, loading `mathalfa` with the option `scr=rsfs` is essentially equivalent to running `\usepackage{mathrsfs}`. The "esstix", "boondox", and "fourier" options provide sets of blackboard bold glyphs with an output of `\mathbb{S}` that should be to your liking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\usepackage[bb=esstix,scr=rsfs,cal=euler]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Special math fonts}
$\mathbb{S}$

\medskip
\texttt{\string\mathbb\ esstix}

$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLM123}$

$\mathbb{NOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\medskip
\texttt{\string\mathscr\ mathrsfs}

$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLM123}$

$\mathscr{NOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\medskip
\texttt{\string\mathcal\ euler}

$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLM123}$

$\mathcal{NOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```